# how to use value from NGXS store in HttpInterceptor?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, ngxs

I'm pretty new to Angular. I am using Angular 6 with NGXS for state management.

My NGXS store has a `user` reducer whose interface is

```js
/* src/app/store/models/user.model.ts */
export interface User {
    serverToken? : string;
    // and other unrelated stuff
}
```

I would like to use `serverToken` in `Authorization` header in a `HttpInterceptor`.

This is my current `HttpInterceptor` codes

```js
import {Store, Select} from '@ngxs/store';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent} from '@angular/common/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {User} from '../store/models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private store : Store) {}
    @Select()user$ : Observable < User >;

    intercept(req : HttpRequest < any >, next : HttpHandler) : Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {
        let options = {
            url: `https://base-url.com/api/${req.url}`
        };

        const serverToken = '???';
        if (serverToken) // if not empty
            options = {
                ...options,
                headers: req
                    .headers
                    .set('Authorization', `JWT ${serverToken}`)
            }

        const duplicate = req.clone(options);

        return next.handle(duplicate);
    }
}
```

so my question is: **How to properly and elegantly use the `user$` observable to get the `serverToken` and use it in `HttpInterceptor` if `serverToken` is not empty?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you prefer a more "observable" approach, try something like:

```
intercept(req : HttpRequest < any >, next : HttpHandler) : Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {

  return this.serverToken$.pipe(
    take(1),
    concatMap(serverToken => {
      if (serverToken) {
        options = {
          ...options,
          headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `JWT ${serverToken}`)
        }
        const duplicate = req.clone(options);
        return next.handle(duplicate)
      } else {
        // next() without changing req
        return next(req)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

You will also need to define a `@Selector` that returns user token and `@Select` it from the interceptor class.

Note: I am not familiar with HTTP interceptor but just applying the concept of chaining RxJS observables based on what I see in the signature of `intercept()`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the [snapshot](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/store#snapshots) feature of NGXS. Not sure if this is the best way. (The snapshot feature is available in NGXS but not in NGRX. I wouldn't know how to solve this in NGRX)

in user.state.ts

```
@State < User > ({name: "user", defaults: {}})
export class UserState {
    // ... 

    @Selector()
    static serverToken(user : User) {
        return user.serverToken || '';
    }
}
```

in `HttpInterceptor`

```
    const serverToken = this
        .store
        .selectSnapshot(UserState.serverToken);
```